# Is it possible to speedup a C++ program using OpenCV with threads ? (On Raspberry A3+)

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I am currently working on a method whose goal is to perform a closing on a binary image, but in such way that any connected components that were not connected still won't be connected after this. Hence I first extract every connected component from my input image using opencv's function `cv::connectedComponents` and then perform closing on temporary images with only one component, before adding these closed components in the end.

This being quite heavy, I decided to multithread this operation and to load 4 threads with a quarter of the job. The thing is that I am not able to measure any difference with the non-threaded version of the code, or by varying the number of threads. The program in which this method is used runs on a raspberry 3A+ (quad-cores).

Am I doing it wrong ? Or maybe opencv's methods already are multithreaded, preventing me to speed things up even more ?

I also tried to manually affect each thread to a dedicated core using `pthread_setaffinity_np` but again it did not change anything.

The code before multithreading :

```cpp
void MyClass::closeConnectedComponents(const cv::Mat& src, cv::Mat& dest, const cv::InputArray& element, const int& connectivity, const int& min_area) const
{
  // A label image, with a value for each connected component
  cv::Mat labels;
  // An image containing only a single connected component on a black background
  cv::Mat current_component;
  // Number of components
  int nb_components;

  // Compute the label image and the number of components
  nb_components = cv::connectedComponents(src, labels, connectivity);
  // Clear destination image
  dest = cv::Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type());
  // For each component (except background)
  for(int i=1; i<nb_components; i++){
    // Create a mask of this component
    current_component = (labels==i);
    // If its area is big enough
    if(cv::countNonZero(current_component) >= min_area){
      // Close the current component
      cv::morphologyEx(current_component, current_component, MORPH_CLOSE, element);
      // Finally add it to the destination image
      cv::bitwise_or(dest, current_component, dest);
    }
  }
  // Scale destination image since for now it is only ones and zeros
  dest *= 0xFF;
}
```

The code after multithreading :

```cpp
void MyClass::closeConnectedComponentsThread(const cv::Mat& labels, cv::Mat& dest_part, const cv::InputArray& element, int min_area, int component_start_i, int component_end_i){
  // An image containing only a single connected component on a black background
  cv::Mat current_component;

  // Process each component from component_start_i (included) to component_end_i (excluded)
  for(int i = component_start_i; i < component_end_i; i++){
    // Create a mask of this component
    current_component = (labels==i);
    // If its area is big enough
    if(cv::countNonZero(current_component) >= min_area){
      // Close the current component
      cv::morphologyEx(current_component, current_component, MORPH_CLOSE, element);
      // Finally add it to the temporary destination image
      cv::bitwise_or(dest_part, current_component, dest_part);
    }
  }
}

void MyClass::closeConnectedComponents(const cv::Mat& src, cv::Mat& dest, const cv::InputArray& element, const int& connectivity, const int& min_area)
{
  // A label image, with a value for each connected component
  cv::Mat labels;
  // Number of components
  int nb_components;
  // The number of components each individual thread will process
  int range;
  // A vector containing each single thread object
  std::vector<std::thread> t(NB_THREADS);
  // A vector containing a temporary destination image for each thread
  std::vector<cv::Mat> dest_temp(NB_THREADS, cv::Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type()));

  // Compute the label image and the number of components
  nb_components = cv::connectedComponents(src, labels, connectivity);
  // Clear destination image
  dest = cv::Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type());

  // Compute the range of each thread
  range = (int)ceil((double)nb_components/NB_THREADS);

  // Start the threads
  for(int i=0; i<NB_THREADS; i++){
    t[i] = std::thread(
      &MyClass::closeConnectedComponentsThread, this,
      labels, std::ref(dest_temp[i]), element, min_area, min(1+i*range, nb_components), min(1+(i+1)*range, nb_components)
    );
  }
  // Wait for each thread to end
  for(int i=0; i<NB_THREADS; i++){
    if(t[i].joinable()){
      t[i].join();
      // Add each temporary image to the output image
      cv::bitwise_or(dest, dest_temp[i], dest);
    }
  }
  // Scale destination image since for now it is only ones and zeros
  dest *= 0xFF;
}
```

Comment: Be somewhat careful with this:
`std::vector<cv::Mat> dest_temp(NB_THREADS, cv::Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type()));`
here you are creating a vector of `NB_THREADS` elements, but with all elements pointing to the _same_ matrix (not `NB_THREADS` distinct matrices). 
(Remember that a `cv::Mat` behaves kinda like a `shared_ptr` in terms of copy/copy assignment semantics)

Comment: I did not think of this, I corrected it by initializing the matrices in the for loop that creates threads. Thank you for the advice !